# Calling Controller's method from Javascript in View

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access a method in the controller by Javascript from View

```
<div id="Historicaldata">
    From Date <input type="date" id="fromDate" /> To Date <input type="date" id="toDate" />
    <a href="#" id="ExportExcel" onclick="GetFromDate()">Export to Excel</a>
</div>

<script>
    function GetFromDate() {

        var dt1 = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
        var dt2 = document.getElementById('toDate').value;
        var url = "~/GeneralStatics/Excel/" + "startdate=" + dt1 + "/endDate=" + dt2;
        alert(url);

            window.location.href = this.href + "startDate=" + document.getElementById('fromDate').value + "&endDate=" + document.getElementById('toDate').value;
            return false;

    };
</script>
```

In my controller there is avoid method like this:

```
 public void Excel(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

by which an Excel file will be downloaded.
what is the best way to do this?
and is it possible doing it without redirection?

Comment: use Post or Get method to pass arguments to your method in the controller, then change the url to be something "clean".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript, you could put the input fields inside an HTML form instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Excel", "SomeControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div id="Historicaldata">
        From Date <input type="date" name="startDate" /> 
        To Date <input type="date" name="endDate" />
        <button type="submit">Export to Excel</button>
    </div>
}
```

Also make sure that your action arguments are matching the names of the input fields and don't forget that in ASP.NET MVC, contorller actions must return ActionResults, not void:

```
public ActionResult Excel(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to download the file:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("Excel", "GeneralStatics")',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     datatype: 'json',
     type: "GET",
     success: function () {
         window.location = '@Url.Action("Excel", "GeneralStatics", new { @startDate= dt1 , @endDate =  dt2 })';
     }
 });
```